# Difference between layer-list and selector - Android XML

Tags: android, xml

When creating a border for example, what is the difference between both?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

```
<selector>
```

> You can describe the state list in an XML file. Each graphic is
>   represented by an `<item>` element inside a single `<selector>` element.
>   Each `<item>` uses various attributes to describe the state in which it
>   should be used as the graphic for the drawable.
>
> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

```
<layer-list>
```

> A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn
>   in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on
>   top.
>
> It can be defined in an XML file with the `<layer-list>` element. Each
>   Drawable in the layer is defined in a nested `<item>`.

For creating a simple border you can just use `<shape>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@null" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```